# How can I instruc0t or configure bash or the desktop to open a Firefox Browser profile?

Tags: try-catch, can-bus

This problem happens in many ways.  Today is the last straw.  In my terminal window, when a program wants to open a URL, it starts-up a browser.  It used to fire-up chrome instead of Firefox (the default browser).  I uninstalled Chrome.  (Yes *I know*, I was in a hurry that night).

So anyway I have two or more Firfox Profiles set-up on my Desktop.  I took some 'time' to think about this beforehand.

I've named the profies with numbers:

- 10_self
- 10_wrk.remote
- 10_daughter
- 10_daughter

Answer (score 0):

Well ... I just figured it out by chance.  Firefox has a few configuration pages.  One interesting page is:

- `about:profiles`

Firefox opens the default profile when it is passed a URL to load.  The name of the profile or short-cut have not effect.  Even a profile named "default" is not selected *as* the default.

The default needs to be set in the `about:profiles` page.